# How do you pronounce "Tech House"?

Tags: pronunciation

I've never heard native english speaker to say "tech house" in a sentence. I'm having hard time guessing whether it sounds like "tek house" or like "tech house" (tetʃ).

Comment: Perhaps you have an English dictionary.  Perhaps it lists "tech".  Perhaps it shows a pronunciation.  There is no reason that adding "house" will change the pronunciation.

Answer (score 1):

Tech is short for technology and the 'ch' is pronounced like the 'ck' in neck, peck, hack, back, sack, crack, etc. Rhymes with neck, peck, trek. Other words with 'ch' sounding like that are listed [here](https://www.spellzone.com/word_lists/list.cfm?wordlist=109).

Comment: it's surely best to move questions like this to ELL